# Put all rows from 1 column in 1 varchar

Tags: php, mysql, string, variables

I have 1 table (in MySQL) with 1 row. The values of that table are for example:

```
5
24
67
```

I select the values with this query:

```
$oudeGetallen = $conn->query("SELECT getal from ingezettegetallen");
```

Now I would like to put the values of that table in 1 text variable in PHP.

So that `$oudeGetallenString = 52467`

I cannot manage that. I tried putting it in an array and use implode after that, but that didn't work. Could you please help me?

Comment: _"I tried putting it in an array and use implode after that"_ That sounds reasonable, post your code and your error messages.

Comment: I think thats a COLUMN no a ROW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are using the MYSQLI extension! This you can do in a number of ways but a simple one is

```
$oudeGetallen = $conn->query("SELECT getal from ingezettegetallen");

$oudeGetallenString = '';
while ( $row = $oudeGetallen->fetch_object()) {
    $oudeGetallenString .= $row->getal;
}
echo $oudeGetallenString;
```

OR

```
$oudeGetallen = $conn->query("SELECT getal from ingezettegetallen");
$arr = [];
while ( $row = $oudeGetallen->fetch_object()) {
    $arr[] = $row->getal;
}
$oudeGetallenString = implode('', $arr);
```

Comment: That works like a charm! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

It is strange to concatenate numeric vales like that, but you can do it with the use of `GROUP_CONCAT()` aggregate function if you specify the empty string `''` as the separator:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(getal SEPARATOR '') AS col
FROM ingezettegetallen;
```

or with an `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(getal ORDER BY getal SEPARATOR '') AS col
FROM ingezettegetallen;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3dd55121eb9ee84882bc80efe6a7a77c).

Comment: Thank you very much, also for the demo. Very useful website!